# ODE Cauchy problem. Solution not unique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Consider the following Cauchy problem:

$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{-t + \sqrt{t^2+4y}}{2} \\
 y(2) = -1 $$

I propose two valid solutions:

$$ y_1(t) = 1 - t \\
y_2(t) = \frac{-t^2}{4} $$

Why does this not contradict the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem related to this kind of questions?

Comment: $y_1(t) $ doesn't satisfy the given equation because $-1-\frac{1}{2}(-t+|t-2|)\ne 0$

Comment: @Raffaele If you are solving the forward in time problem, $y_1$ is in fact a solution. But I agree that if nothing is said we must seek a solution defined for $t \in ]2-\delta, 2+ \delta[$.

Answer (score 2):

The existence an uniqueness theorems (like the Picard-Lindelof Theorem) have conditions... If the conditions are not met there is no contradiction.

edit: It was noted in comments to the OP that, strictly speaking, $y_1$ is in not a solution of the Cauchy problem, even though it is a solution of the forward problem ($t>2$).

Answer (score 1):

The equation is one of the solution of the equation
$$y'(t)^2+t y'(t)-y(t)=0\quad\quad(1)$$
which gives
$$y_1'(t)=\frac{-t+\sqrt{t^2+4y}}{2}\quad\quad(2)$$
and
$$y_2'(t)=\frac{-t-\sqrt{t^2+4y}}{2}\quad\quad(3)$$
differentiate $(1)$ wrt $t$
$$t y''(t)+2 y'(t) y''(t)=0$$
Collect $y''(t)$
$$y''(t)(t+2y'(t))=0$$
we get two solutions
$$y_1(t)=1-t$$
and
$$y_2(t)=-\frac{t^2}{4}$$
but solution $y_1(t)$ doesn't satisfy the given equation $(2)$ while $y_2(t)$ does.

Thus the unique solution of the given equation is $y_2(t)=-\frac{t^2}{4}$.